# Showing image using ternary operator with AngularJs Data Binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to use angular.js ternary operator to show an image, I was wondering if there was a way to achieve something like the following

```
{{enquiry.buyer_email ? <img ng-src="/images/ico_yes.png"> : <img ng-src="/images/ico_no.png"> }}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a mistake in your paths because they are the same, so I'm going to use `ico_no.png` instead for one of the cases.

You could do something like this with ternary operators (Angular >= 1.1.5):

```
<img ng-src="{{enquiry.buyer_email ? '/images/ico_yes.png' : '/images/ico_no.png'}}">
```

Or something like this with binary operators:

```
<img ng-src="{{enquiry.buyer_email && '/images/ico_yes.png' || '/images/ico_no.png'}}">
```

or you could use `ng-show`:

```
<img ng-src="/images/ico_yes.png" ng-show="enquiry.buyer_email">
<img ng-src="/images/ico_no.png" ng-show="!enquiry.buyer_email">
```

Comment: So sorry yes that was the correct path. Thank you so much your first solution worked like a charm!

Comment: Is there a way to use it with the ternary operator though?

Comment: I see you fixed it :)

Comment: I just updated the answer to cover the ternary operator

Comment: @Oh another fix, thank you for this ill mark it as correct answer ;)

Comment: You are welcome. Just note that the ternary operator like I used in the answer are available only in versions >=1.1.5. Earlier versions only support the binary operator.